# HTML: How do i make body stay in the same spot

Tags: html, css, document-body

I'm toying around with a website and I have trouble getting my text areas to stay in one spot.

I have the background set to cover, but now I just need the login and password button to stay in one spot no matter if you resize or not.

http://refractify.webuda.com/index.php

HTML code here

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/ico" 
      href="favicon.ico">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MewSeek | &lt;3</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
        background-size: cover;
    background-color: #0c0c0c;
    background-image: url(images/MewSeek.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}


textarea {

          resize: none;
          text-align: center;
          font-color: #0F9;
          font-size:26px;
          color: #0F9;
          background-color: transparent;
          position: relative; 
          height: 35px;
width:343px!important; font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
</script>
</head>
<div id="wrapper">
<body onLoad="MM_preloadImages('images/button2.png')">
<table width="1879" height="666" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="819" height="396">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="257">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="789">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="36">&nbsp;</td>
    <div>
     <td>
       <p>
        <textarea maxlength="9" placeholder="Username"></textarea>
       </p>
      </div>
      <p>
        <div>
         <textarea maxlength="9" placeholder="Password"></textarea>
        </div>    
       </p></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="21">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="38">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="108">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><a href="http://google.com" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Login','','images/button2.png',1)"><img src="images/button1.png" alt="" width="380" height="70" id="Login"></a></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: You'd be better off making JUST the grey image the background (BTW, take a small slice, and repeat it, so it's not a massive image), then placing a div container with the black area (and containing the text inputs) and position it in the middle of the page.  Disconnecting the black area from the inputs that belong inside of it is a bad approach.

Comment: How would I be able to make a table and input the textareas in the table, since the image would be larger than the text boxes

Answer (score 1):

Several points:

(1) Why use tables for such a simple layout.
(2) Having sound start automatically is a horrible idea. What if I'm at work without headphones on? Not good.

Re your problem. If you're talking about keeping the username/password in the same relative spot then

(1) using floats would work well. 
(2) If you're talking about keeping them exactly in the same position then absolutes would work as well. Keep everything absolutely positioned in the center and it will stay in the same position as you re-sized. However I think that absolute positioning would NOT be the way to go. Floats would probably be the better solution.

Comment: For the first part, I was messing around in code figuring out if I could play music via a download link, went to bed before i took off the tags, for the second I will try this when i get home.

Comment: Are you comfortable with creating a responsive design with floats?